# Generate a unique Id on MySql with 00 at the end

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please show me how to genetate an Id on a field called employee_id with a number that starts with 07 and end with 00. There should be 11 digits in total. An example is 07016504500

Comment: what you have try?

Comment: What do you want to do? Set a constraint?

Comment: So, you merely want to know how to generate a seven digit number (the middle part)? Or do you want to know how to concatenate '07', a seven-digit-number, and '00'? If you are looking for a seven-digit number generator: Do you want random numbers or can they be consecutive? Do you have employee rows and want to add that number to the existing rows? Or do you want to create an employee table and have the number generated on insert?  Or what else?

Answer (score 0):

you can generate 11 digits unique id using below function

```
function generateUnqiueId(){
      $startStr = '07'; // id start with
    $endStr = '00'; // id end with
    $totalStrLength = 11;// id total length
    
    
    // Get remaining string length by subtract start and end string
    $remainingStr = $totalStrLength - (strlen($startStr) + strlen($endStr));
    $number = "0123456789"; // random number
    $uniqueNumer = substr(str_shuffle($number),0,$remainingStr);
    
    // generate unique id
    $uniqueId = $startStr.$uniqueNumer.$endStr;
    echo ($uniqueId);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. I will go with your answer